# REST POST endpoint to download csv file

Tags: java, spring, rest, csv

I am trying below code to download csv file with POST REST endpoint.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "export",
        notes = "Export Report as a CSV")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/export")
public ResponseEntity export( @RequestBody SearchCriteria criteria )
{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMddHHmm" );
    SAStatsManager saStatsManager = new SAStatsManager();
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource;
    InputStream inputStream;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    try
    {
        inputStreamResource = saStatsManager.export( criteria );

        if ( inputStreamResource == null )
        {
            return new ResponseEntity( "Error in exporting report!!! ", HttpStatus.OK );
        }
        httpHeaders.set( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + REPORT_NAME+ criteria.getProductCombination() + "_" + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".csv" );

        //convert inputStream to bytes
        inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        while ( ( nRead = inputStream.read( data, 0, data.length ) ) != -1 )
        {
            buffer.write( data, 0, nRead );
        }

        buffer.flush();
        byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

        httpHeaders.setContentLength( byteArray.length );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity( byteArray, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK );

}
```

This work without any exception. But this doesn't download any file. How to download .csv file once call on this rest endpoint.

**EDITED**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "export",
        notes = "Export Report as a CSV")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/export", produces = "text/csv")
public ResponseEntity export( @RequestBody SearchCriteria criteria )
{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMddHHmm" );
    SAStatsManager saStatsManager = new SAStatsManager();
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource;
    InputStream inputStream;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    try
    {
        inputStreamResource = saStatsManager.export( criteria );

        if ( inputStreamResource == null )
        {
            return new ResponseEntity( "Error in exporting report!!! ", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
        }
        httpHeaders.set( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + REPORT_NAME + criteria.getProductCombination() + "_" + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".csv" );

        //convert inputStream to bytes
        inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        while ( ( nRead = inputStream.read( data, 0, data.length ) ) != -1 )
        {
            buffer.write( data, 0, nRead );
        }

        buffer.flush();
        byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

        httpHeaders.setContentLength( byteArray.length );

        return new ResponseEntity( byteArray, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity( e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
    }

}
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks You

Comment: What response do you get back?

Comment: Response Body give a download url (blob:http://localhost:8080/de7b6de7-9f52-4485-bef5-2f1e43cedd99) and it downloads File type file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017495/spring-mvc-excel-file-download-corrupts-file/27018596#27018596

Comment: down vote
I have a few comments.

The first is that you should try and handle the error/exceptions better, and always return the appropriate http code. For instance if your import stream is null you are returning a message and code 200, perhaps this should be 500? Or maybe 404, or 400? Also you are catching an ioexception and not doing anything, so then just returning as normal, this also should be returning a proper http error code.

Additionally your method does not have a "produces" in the request mapping annotation.

Try fixing these things then see how things are working.

Comment: @MartinByers, Thanks for your explanation. I fixed the thing that u have pointed out and used "produces" annotation. Please seen my question under **EDITED**. However, the result is same as before.

Comment: What response code are you receiving?

Comment: Have you tried using nettool to tunnel so you can see what is being sent between the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting URL then try passing that URL to get the file object from it as

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File);
```

Hope it will work.